# LWC Quick Action not being loaded from URL

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction

I'm facing an issue when trying to open a quick action from the URL

`https://salesforce-instance/lightning/action/quick/Lead.MyQuickAction?objectApiName&context=RECORD_DETAIL&recordId=00Q78000001PfS6EAK&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FLead%2F00Q78000001PfS6EAK%2Fview`

Basically the Action never gets to be loaded.
[image]

An on my component I defined the function `connectedCallback` just to check if there was something wrong, but the function never gets to get call.

```
export default class MyQuickAction extends LightningElement {
  
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('Getting loaded')
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you look at the HTML, your component isn't here. So I think it's a Platform bug. I asked about it in the Trailblazer Community a while back but never got any answer. You can still create a Case if you want to get it solved and post the answer/Known Issue link here.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug, see here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371521/quick-action-is-not-loading-lwc-while-reloading-the-page

Comment: thanks @Fabien Taillon, yeah, seems like it's. I guess we are going to need to wait for the fix.