# Quick action is not loading LWC while reloading the page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-quickaction

I am calling an LWC component on a quick-action click. I get an infinite loading (See image Link) when I reload the page without closing quick action.
[image]

Video Link: https://www.loom.com/share/e6ac68e45daa42bd967265e1dbc84b5b

LWC is not being loaded.

Comment: Share code as well.

Comment: It's just a simple LWC component with H1 tag

Comment: Problem here is on reload without closing the quick action the LWC component is not loaded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update*: This was fixed with Summer '22

---

This is a known bug (*no public known issue*, W-10027362). It's currently scheduled to be fixed in Summer '22 (*safe harbor*).

If you pay attention to the URL, you'll notice it changes after a refresh so there's unfortunately no workaround for it until it's fixed.

Comment: I do not think this is fixed still as I am still facing the issue, quick action just keeps loading but doesn't actually render LWC.

Comment: In my local org, I'm not seeing the issue fwiw. The change, though I can't say whether something else has impacted it, did go out with Summer '22. I would reach out to support or debug whether it's only one specific quick action displaying the behavior?

Comment: it does seem like it’s specific to LWC but the same LWC works in lightning tab where as here it’s not even inserted to the DOM. Any lifecycle hooks are not called

Comment: If you're able to create a separate question (or create a support case), that might be helpful as it would allow you to put more details to see if it can be replicated (like your LWC code, etc)

Comment: I did create a separate question, thank you. Will also create a support case but sf support just isn't great with timely response :)