# LWC keeps loading on quick action and lightning__recordPage

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, quickaction

I have the LWC created for LWR Site that I am also using on Lightning quick action on Contact object.

When I click the quick action, I just get loading screen infinitely and LWC never loads.

[image]

here's the meta.xml

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
</targets>
```

I also tried adding the LWC to record page and it doesn't let me save, just throws unknown error.

I read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371521/quick-action-is-not-loading-lwc-while-reloading-the-page/371524?noredirect=1#comment568306_371524) that it was known issue but fixed by SF but I still see the issue in full sandbox.

It worked once and then suddenly stopped loading. How do I get LWC to load on quick action or record page?

HTML:

```
<template if:true={recordId}></template>
```

Simplified JS:

```
@api objectApiName;
@api recordId;
   
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: USER_ID,
    fields: [NAME_FIELD, EMAIL_FIELD, LANGUAGE_FIELD]
})
wireuser({ error, data }) {
    //console.groupCollapsed('User Detail');
    if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.showUnexpectedError = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.error('Error fetching User information : '+JSON.stringify(error));
    } else if (data) {
        this.name = data.fields.Name.value;
        this.email = data.fields.Email.value;

    }
```

Comment: If you open the browser Developer Tools, are there any errors being thrown? From past experiences, this kind of infinite loading is often due to a JavaScript error that has caused the component to not load correctly but not completely failed and shown an error to the user.

Comment: No errors are being thrown, also the same component is working perfectly fine in an LWR site and a lightning tab under the same user context so it's really confusing what the error could be specific to quick action.

Comment: So the known issue was reloading the page with the quick action open after it had been loaded successfully already - this sounds like it never loads ever from the quick action on first click? Are you able to share any logic in the javascript or a simplified version of what it is? Ex. Are you getting [record Id](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347055/is-recordid-passed-to-lwc-in-a-quick-action/347058#347058) which might not be working in quick action and holding up loading, do you have a loading spinner on your component/if conditions, etc.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I added simplified version of my JS file. And not setting recordId could very well be the issue as I know with quickAction it's different setting that but my `spinner` doesn't load and none of the lifecycle hook's `console.log` statements.

I had referred to the answer you linked but let me try that again and I will get back. thank you for taking time. Also, I am using `recordId` in HTML so I thought I do not need to set it in renderedCallBack.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I tried everything including renderedCallback, even commented my code out but for some reason the component is just not loading, any wire method, lifecycle hook are not logging anything. Also, it definitely is component related as I created a test LWC with just `h1` tag and it works fine.

Comment: Are you missing defining the `actionType` that it's a screen action under the `targetconfigs` or did you just not include that in the question? See the doc for [example](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232)

Comment: I actually have defined it, I created a new LWC and didn't explicitly define actionType but it still works. It's really weird that it's specific to that LWC.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I figured out what was causing the problem for this LWC.

I had an import `import basePath from "@salesforce/community/basePath";` because I was using my LWC in a experience builder site, in salesforce it just keeps spinning and doesnt actually load the basepath.

seems like a salesforce LWC bug I am going to figure out a way to submit that to SF.

Comment: Ah, that's actually documented behavior [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_community_info). `If a component imports @salesforce/community or @salesforce/site, it can target only an Experience Builder page. You can’t use the component in any other Salesforce container`

Comment: oh well, my lack of research I guess. Thanks for pointing me to it.

Anyway I can get community `basePath` in LWC other than the import? since I do want to use LWC both in community and Salesforce lightning QA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this LWC was being used in `community` and `lightning tab` and `lightning quick action`, I had multiple import statements for both targets.

The infinite loading in lightning quick action was because I had an import statement for community `import basePath from "@salesforce/community/basePath";` which is not allowed in other containers than community.

I commented the import statement and quick action can render LWC just fine.
It's really surprising that SF is not throwing some useful error.